# How do I make a the console.log count from 1 to 32?

Tags: javascript

So I was thinking something like

```
number = 1;
maxnum = 32;
cat = true;

if (cat == true){
number + 1;
}
```

something along those lines, but I don't know how to implement that into making a constant changing line of number from 1 to 32; On the console.log.

Comment: Google is your friend. All you have to do is add console.log(number); to your loop and do a test in side for if number == maxnum cat = false  But seriously, Google should be your first stop for questions like this.

Comment: `var i = 0; while(i<33){console.log(i++);}`

Comment: just a loop...its just a loop

Comment: @oPi we all went through this.. don't make him feel bad about this  TBH, it just programming.. not life. :)

Comment: no...we should make him feel bad for not having research skill to enter into google search phrases like "how to use javascript console.log" and "how  to increment integers in javascript"

Comment: well @Mr_Green you're right, but its a really simply search xD

Answer (score 1):

```
maxnum = 32;

for(var i=0; i<maxnum; i++}{
console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
   var num = 1;
   var maxnum = 32;
   for(var i = num; i <= maxnum; i++){
      console.log(i);
    }
```

use the variable, i, in the for loop as a counter.  Each round through the loop, 'i' will increment by one.  [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) will give you some good practice and basic info on for loops. [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) is for more in depth study on the javascript language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'for' loop:

```
var maxnum = 32;

for (var i=1; i<maxnum; ++i) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 1,
    maxnum = 32;

while (i <= maxnum){
    console.log(i++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop in your answer, either a for loop or a while loop.

If you change your if statement to a while loop, for example, and you can do this as follows.

```
number = 1;
maxnum = 32;
cat = true;

// Change "if" to "while" to make it a loop
while (cat == true){
    // Add the following line to print:
    console.log(number);

    // Update the "cat" variable:
    cat = (number < 32);

    // Make sure this line uses assignment:
    number += 1;
}
```

However, a for loop is a much cleaner solution.  See the other answers posted here for examples of how to use a for loop.